# Is it meaningful to allow parties to use a non-uniform random tape in 2-party computation?

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation

Consider a trivial example where two **semi-honest** parties want to flip a **biased** coin. Since the sender is semi-honest, the sender can locally flip a biased coin and send it to the receiver. A natural question is: What does the sender's random tape look like in the above trivial real protocol?

I know that, in the 2-party computation literature, the random tape is assumed to be uniformly random. I am curious about the convention of such an assumption. Is it a mandatory requirement? Many thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, **it is not a mandatory requirement in cryptography**.

Recently, there has been a significant amount of attention given to two or more party protocols that start off with **correlated randomness**. This randomness is derived in an offline phase and extended during an online phase. Imagine giving two people two different PRG keys that produce "random streams" that are jointly correlated.

Because parties start off with this correlated randomness, they are able to obtain more efficient protocols in terms of communication or computation.

Almost all of the recent works of [Elette Boyle](https://cs.idc.ac.il/%7Eelette/) are based on this premise. I will highlight some examples:

1. Efficient Pseudorandom Correlation Generators from Ring-LPN
2. Secure Multiparty Computation with Sublinear Preprocessing

Also, any work that mentions "Vector Oblivious Linear Evaluation" or VOLE or Vector-OLE really just uses correlated randomness behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Most models I've come across have a truly random tape. You can use this trick - assume the tape to be uniformly random, but then the party reads a block (of certain size) of random bits and uses that to bias the coin.

For example, if you want the coin to output Heads by probability 0.75, read 2 random bits from the random tape and if they both are 1's, output Heads otherwise output Tails.